# Issue with the T-SQL Replace function

Tags: sql-server, replace

I'm currently facing a strange situation.

I'm collecting code of existing stored procedures from a query to a `TMP` table.

TABLE:

```
##SPListAndCode
(
    Code nVarchar(MAX)
)
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO ##SPListAndCode
    SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('SPname')))
```

After that I am trying to replace values to get from Create query, Alter query

```
REPLACE(CODE, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
```

But problem is this: `REPLACE` function is not replacing values.

But, when I am trying to use

```
REPLACE(CODE, 'CREATE', 'ALTER')
```

function works as expected.

But this scenario are not acceptable for me, because inside the stored procedure there can be things like

```
CREATE TABLE
```

Example data inside "Code" column:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure dbo.spName    Script Date: 6/20/2016 9:10:18 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE  PROCEDURE dbo.spName
AS
DECLARE  @pStartDate  date, @x int


SET @pStartDate  = (SELECT max(CT_ACTIVITY_DATE) FROM Table)

...
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any kind of support!

Comment: how are you populating `##SPListAndCode`

Comment: `REPLACE` should had done the trick. But to debug more could you please show us the code  - 1. where you are populating `##SPListAndCode` and 2. your query to `REPLACE` string/keywords

Comment: @Tanner
Code for populating ##SPListAndCode was added.

Comment: Change your replace to the first one you posted. And be careful here....this is a global temp table which means that any connection can see it and modify it. If you have two people running this at the same time you have exposed yourself to concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure has two spaces between CREATE and PROCEDURE, while your replace is looking for the string with a single space between the words.

Comment: Thank MATE !
this was an issue
Double SPACE

Answer (score 0):

To gain access to the actual code contained inside of the stored procedures, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    so.name [ObjectName], so.type, 
    OBJECT_NAME(sc.id), sc.id, sc.colid , sc.[text]
FROM 
    sys.syscomments sc
INNER JOIN 
    sys.sysobjects so ON so.id = sc.id
WHERE 
    so.type = 'P'
ORDER BY 
    sc.id, sc.colid
```

Note there can be multiple entries for each object, and the colid is used to order those entries.

Comment: Or you could use the `sys.procedures` catalog view (instead of `sys.sysobjects`) and then you don't need the `WHERE so.type = 'P'` clause anymore...